# One Database or Many for multiple clients?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm creating a Microsoft SQL server that initially only served one client but am now looking to have many (Up to several thousand if things go well). The entire structure will be the same for each client with only the data within each table being client specific.

I am thinking of adding ClientID to almost all tables and referencing this in all functions (basically a where ClientID = @ClientID on every statement). Along with a Clients table that gains a new entry for every new client

The alternative being a create database [Client_Name] script that is fired whenever a new client joins the server to create another client specific database and all its associated structure and procedures.

Is there any advantage performance wise to either option?

Comment: I prefer add Client id and query with client id because it is one time activity, If you go with second option as creating separate DB for every client at the end you have burden to handle thousands of DB if client increases frequently. It is easy to manage one DB to handle all client data.

Comment: And for performance you can cluster the database server.

Comment: If you decide you need another column in a table, do you want to add it once or 1000 times?

Comment: The masochist in me says 1000 times, the hedonist says once.

Comment: One more option to create Mapping tables with client id so that your existing DB structure will not affect.

Comment: As you say "adding ClientID to almost all tables", I take it you are using composite primary keys and want to extend those primary keys with the Client ID?

Comment: I'm not currently using any composites and ClientID would just be a Foreign Key linking back to a Clients Table

Comment: Then maybe you don't have to add the client ID to so many tables. If there is a kind of main table (e.g. the product table in a product database) it may suffice to only add the client ID to this main table and few others (e.g. the suppliers table). Child tables (product attributes, product suppliers, supplier orders) would implicitly be linked to the client.

Comment: I get where you're going, I have a Prize Categories table that is constant across all clients, PrizeTypes has an FK to this and would receive a unique clientid so that clients can make their own PrizeTypes of certain categories. From there, there is Prizes which links to PrizeTypes with an FK so it wouldn't need a ClientID as my joins would eliminate any other client's prizes. I'll just have to be consistent with my statements to avoid any crossovers.

Comment: @NotADog I don't have much to add to Gordon's awesome answer, except that if you do decide on keeping one DB, you might want to look into Virtual Private Databases (aka Virtualization).  You are using MS SQL Server, which, last I heard does not support VPD functions by default, but you can replicate the concept using Views.  Or maybe a better method has been developed since the last time I've used SQL Server.

Comment: The nightmare for one single DB would be customization. I had the same problem and the best way is to keep the customization at the front end level

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decision on how to structure such a database should not be made only on performance issues.  In fact, that is probably the least of the issues.  Some things to consider:

- How will you manage updates to your application?  Multiple databases can make this easier or harder.
- Will individual clients have customizations?  This favors multiple databases.
- What are the security requirements for the data?  This can go either way.
- What are the replication and recovery requirements for the data?  This would tend to be easier with one database, but not in all scenarios.
- Will concurrent usage by different clients interfere with each other?
- Will clients be responsible for managing their own data or is this part of your offering?
- Is any data shared among clients?  How will you maintain common reference tables?

In general, performance is going to be better with a single database (think half-filled data pages occupying memory).  Maintenance and development will be easier with a single database (managing multiple client databases is cumbersome).  But actual requirements on the application should be driving such a decision.

Comment: I'd also add: Is there (or will there ever be) any data that is shared between clients?

Comment: The application is fairly simple it sits on an application server, calling apis and monitoring IRC chatrooms to collect data. Data from this is fed into ~10 stored procedures that insert the collected data into the relevant tables which triggers a plethora of other actions depending on the data content. Any "Output" required is entered into an output table that the application reads from periodically using another stored procedure. The only customisations will be in output text but that is handled by values in a "customisation" table and either the default or @CustomXValue used.